# How to add an ID to an image in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Everytime a user inserts an image into the page (I'm using CKEditor 4 inline editing) I want to add an ID sequentially e.g. `id=Image1`, `id=Image2`, `id=Image3` so that my server can loop through them and know how many images there are on the page and how to process them.

I noticed there is an `addClass()`  function in CKEditor, but how do I add an ID? I just need some way to uniquely and programmatically tell each inserted image apart from the other.

I can't understand how to do this at all. Even a pointer in the right direction would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the element using something like:

```
var myImg = document.createElement('img');
```

then you can add an id to by simply setting the id property of that new DOM element:-

```
myImg.id = "Image1";
```

Comment: I'm working on a Jquery alternative now. I don't think CKEditor can do it without some expert knowledge